# Create a function get_algorithm_result to implement an algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

Create a function get_algorithm_result to implement the algorithm below

```
Get a list of numbers L1, L2, L3....LN as argument
Assume L1 is the largest, Largest = L1
Take next number Li from the list and do the following
If Largest is less than Li
Largest = Li
If Li is last number from the list then
return Largest and come out
Else repeat same process starting from step 3
```

here's my code here:

```
def get_algorithm_result(listNumb):
 largest = listNumb[0]
 i = 1
 for i in range(i, len(listNumb)):
  if largest < listNumb[i]:
   largest = listNumb[i]
   i =i + 1
   continue
 return largest


>>> print( get_algorithm_result([4,7,1,9,12,2,1]) )
4
```

what am i getting wrong? i expect it to return/print the largest number for any give list called on get_algorithm_result().

Comment: Please add a language tag if you're looking for answers in a particular language.

Comment: Is the "largetest" typo in your actual code?

Comment: Isn't this just python

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm skips numbers because it both (1) uses a for..in and also (2) increments i in the body.

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution after much hacking:
`def get_algorithm_result(listNumb):
    largest = listNumb[0]
    for i in range(1, len(listNumb)):
        if largest < listNumb[i]:
            largest = listNumb[i]
        continue
    return largest`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to track or assign a value to `i` (you don't need `i` at all) you just need to track which value is the largest:

```
>>> def get_largest(listNumb):
...    largest = listNumb[0] # assume first value is the largest
...    for value in listNumb: # Take next number Li from the list
...       if largest < value: # If Largest is less than Li
...           largest = value # Largest = Li
...    return largest
...
>>> get_largest([1,1,1,32,42,5423,-1,4])
5423
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses a while loop. I have also tried to take care of the conditions:
 - If Li is last number from the list then
 - return Largest and come out

```
def get_algorithm_result(items):
    largest=items[0]
    i=0
    while i<len(items):
        if largest<items[i]:
            largest=items[i]
        if items[i]==items[len(items)-1]:
          return largest  
        i+=1

lst=[34,67,64,22,64,570,67,87,99]
get_algorithm_result(lst)
print("Largest item:%s"% (get_algorithm_result(lst)))
Result:
Largest item:570
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting an answer please consider adding text to explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_algorithm_result(numbers):
  largest = numbers[0]
  for i in numbers:
    if largest < i:
      largest = i
return largest
```

Comment: Could be improved with some more explanation of how it solves the question.

Comment: The question is to simple print the largest number in a list. But in this case, we are to follow their instruction by first assuming the first number is the largest.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

```
def get_algorithm_result(num_list):    
    largest =num_list[0]        
    for item in range(0,len(num_list)):    
        if largest < num_list[item]:                
            largest = num_list[item]    
    return largest
```